# unidentified com_error in python

Tags: python, com

I've encountered the following error while scripting in Python.

ERROR      Tue 19. Jan 14:51:21 2010 C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client\util.py:0: Script Error
com_error: (-2147217385, 'OLE error 0x80041017', None, None)

Unfortunately, I don't know what it means, or even what other information I might need to find out. Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Could you post a code snippet that reproduces the error?

Comment: Someone found [this](http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html) useful

Answer (score 1):

Here's a page at the [Microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394559%28VS.85%29.aspx) which might shed some light:

```
WBEM_E_INVALID_QUERY
2147749911 (0x80041017)
Query was not syntactically valid.
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing python COM programming, I sometimes use VBA (in Excel) to test code that gives errors.

That way, I can see if the problem is in the Python-COM layer, or if I get the same error when  using VBA. I have sometimes seen that the error messages in VBA have descriptions that the Python exception lacks.

VBA is quite nice for doing COM programming. You have tab completion/intellisense in the editor.

Comment: VBA, COM, and "nice" shouldn't all appear in the same sentence!